Re-render Buffer data from streaming API with React
I'm having issues with this feature where I need to re-render a parent component that has  a list of accordion components. The data to re-render the component is coming from a buffer stream API every 200 ms. I'm using SSE (server send event) to fetch the data because Web sockets was not a option. My main goal is to find a way to render the component that has the accordions with the buffer data without crashing the page. Can someone please help me on this subject?
The method I'm using to fetch the data from the buffer API:
export function useLiveTail(sourceId, filter) {
  const [liveTailData, setLiveTailData] = useState([]);
  const eventSourceRef = useRef(null);
  const recordLimit = 50000;

  const closeEventSource = () => {
    if (eventSourceRef.current) {
      eventSourceRef.current.close();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!sourceId) return;
    closeEventSource();
    setLiveTailData([])

    const queryParams = filter ? `?filter=${encodeURIComponent(filter)}` : '';
    eventSourceRef.current = new EventSource(`${baseURL}/v1/livetail/${sourceId}${queryParams}`);

    eventSourceRef.current.onmessage = (event) => {
      const newData = JSON.parse(event.data);
      // liveTailBufferRef.current.push(newData);

      setLiveTailData(((prevData) => {
        const updatedData = [...prevData, newData];
        // Apply record limit
       if (updatedData.length > recordLimit) {
        return updatedData.slice(-recordLimit); 
      }
        return updatedData
      }))

    };

    eventSourceRef.current.onerror = (error) => {
      closeEventSource();
    };

    return () => closeEventSource();

  }, [sourceId, filter]);



  return { liveTailData , closeEventSource };
}

My parent component with the accordions:
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Grid, Box, Paper, Accordion, AccordionSummary, AccordionDetails, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { ExpandMore, FilterAlt } from '@mui/icons-material';
import CustomBreadcrumbs from '../../components/Globals/CustomBreadcrumbs';
import { lightTheme, darkTheme } from '../../globalStyles';
import { AuthContext } from '../../AuthContext';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import CustomInputSelect from '../../components/Globals/CustomInputSelect';
import CustomButton from '../../components/Globals/CustomButton';
import CustomInput from '../../components/Globals/CustomInput';
import { getSourceList } from '../../API/Sources/Sources';
import { mockTaxonamy } from '../../assets/flags/mockData';
import moment from 'moment';
import HoverDescription from './Componentes/HoverDescription';
import { useLiveTail } from '../../API/Live Tail/Live Tail';

// Component to determine JSON data color
const getValueColor = (value) => {
  if (typeof value === 'number') return 'blue';
  if (typeof value === 'string') return 'green';
  if (typeof value === 'boolean' || value === null) return 'orange';
  return 'black';
};

// Recursive rendering of JSON with color
const renderJsonWithColors = (obj, level = 0) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).map((key, index) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    const valueTypeColor = getValueColor(value);

    return (
      <Box key={index} display="flex" flexDirection="row" paddingLeft={level * 20}>
        <Typography sx={{ color: 'purple', fontWeight: 'bold', marginRight: '8px' }}>
          "{key}":
        </Typography>
        {typeof value === 'object' && value !== null ? (
          <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" marginLeft="8px">
            <Typography>{"{"}</Typography>
            {renderJsonWithColors(value, level + 1)}
            <Typography>{"}"}</Typography>
          </Box>
        ) : (
          <Typography sx={{ color: valueTypeColor, marginLeft: '8px' }}>
            {typeof value === 'string' ? `"${value}"` : `${value}`}
          </Typography>
        )}
      </Box>
    );
  });
};

const LiveTail = () => {
  const { userData } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const theme = Cookies.get(`theme_${userData.email}`);
  const breadCrumbsData = [{ label: 'Sources', href: '/sources' }];

  // States
  const [sourceList, setSourceList] = useState([]);
  const [currentSource, setCurrentSource] = useState();
  const [auxFilter, setAuxFilter] = useState('');
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  const [hoveredAccordion, setHoveredAccordion] = useState(null);
  const [visibleRecords, setVisibleRecords] = useState(5); // Number of records to load initially
  const paperRef = useRef(null); // Ref for the scrolling container
  const { liveTailData, closeEventSource } = useLiveTail(currentSource, filter);
  const sortedLiveTailData = liveTailData.sort((a, b) => moment(a.timestamp).diff(moment(b.timestamp)));

  // Handlers
  const handleSourceChange = (event) => {
    setCurrentSource(event.target.value);
    setAuxFilter('');
  };

  const handleFilterChange = (event) => {
    setAuxFilter(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleAccordionChange = (panel) => (event, isExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
  };

  const handleMouseEnter = (id) => {
    setHoveredAccordion(id);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setHoveredAccordion(null);
  };

  const handleSetFilter = () => {
    setFilter(auxFilter);
  };

  const handleCopyContent = (content, event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(content)
      .then(() => {
        alert('Content copied to clipboard');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Failed to copy content: ', err);
      });
  };

  // Scroll event handler for lazy loading
  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (paperRef.current) {
      const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = paperRef.current;
      if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 10) {
        // User has reached the bottom, load more data
        setVisibleRecords((prev) => Math.min(prev + 20, sortedLiveTailData.length));
      }
    }
  };

  // Fetch source list
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSourceList = async () => {
      try {
        const aux = await getSourceList();
        const newArray = aux.data.data.items.map((item) => ({
          label: item.name,
          value: item.id,
        }));

        setSourceList(newArray);

        if (newArray.length > 0) {
          setCurrentSource(newArray[0].value);
        } else {
          setCurrentSource(null);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching source list:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchSourceList();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundColor: theme === 'light' ? lightTheme.background : darkTheme.background,
        height: '100%',
        overflow: 'hidden',
      }}
    >
      <Grid container>
        <Grid style={{ padding: '0px 20px 20px 0px' }} item xs={12}>
          <CustomBreadcrumbs links={breadCrumbsData}></CustomBreadcrumbs>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container spacing={1} alignItems="center" justifyContent="space-between">
        <Grid item xs={3} style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
          <CustomInputSelect
            name="sourceSelected"
            value={currentSource || ''}
            options={sourceList}
            onChange={handleSourceChange}
            fullWidth={true}
            disabled={false}
          />
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={6} style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <div style={{ marginRight: '10px', width: '270px' }}>
            <CustomInput
              name="filter"
              value={auxFilter}
              placeholder={'Filter'}
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={handleFilterChange}
              fullWidth={true}
              disabled={false}
            />
          </div>
          <CustomButton
            background={theme === 'light' ? lightTheme.buttons.primary.background : darkTheme.buttons.primary.background}
            color={theme === 'light' ? lightTheme.buttons.primary.text : darkTheme.buttons.primary.text}
            hoverColor={theme === 'light' ? lightTheme.buttons.primary.hover : darkTheme.buttons.primary.hover}
            text="Filter"
            action={handleSetFilter}
            float={false}
            icon={<FilterAlt />}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <Grid container style={{ height: '100%' }}>
        <Grid item style={{ height: '100%' }} xs={12}>
          <Box sx={{ padding: '16px 0px', width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
            <Grid style={{ height: '100%' }} container>
              <Grid style={{ height: '100%' }} item xs={12}>
                <Paper
                  ref={paperRef}
                  onScroll={handleScroll}
                  elevation={10}
                  sx={{ mb: 2, height: '100%', overflowY: 'auto' }}
                >
                  {sortedLiveTailData.slice(0, visibleRecords).map((item, index) => (
                    <Accordion
                      key={item.id}
                      expanded={expanded === `panel${index}`}
                      onChange={handleAccordionChange(`panel${index}`)}
                      onMouseEnter={() => handleMouseEnter(item.id)}
                      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
                    >
                      <AccordionSummary
                        expandIcon={<ExpandMore />}
                        aria-controls={`panel${index}-content`}
                        id={`panel${index}-header`}
                        sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}
                      >
                        <HoverDescription
                          row={item}
                          taxonomy={mockTaxonamy}
                          onCopy={handleCopyContent}
                          hoveredAccordion={hoveredAccordion}
                        />
                      </AccordionSummary>
                      <AccordionDetails>{renderJsonWithColors(item)}</AccordionDetails>
                    </Accordion>
                  ))}
                </Paper>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LiveTail;

I already tried lazy loading but it didn't work because this can have 50000 records...

Why is the page crashing? Do you have a more minimal example?

The page after some re-renders of the accordions list, stops and freezes
